# Components are being rendered twice in REACT

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-custom-hooks

Every time any component in the defined AppRoutes is rendered, it calls the getUser() hook and all the functions called when the component mounts twice which essentially means the component is rendered twice and i cant seem to figure out why.

Any insight would be really helpful.

Cheers!

I have a HomeContainer, which wraps the entire REACT project:

```
function HomeContainer() {

  const { user, authenticated } = useUser();
  const [toggled, setToggled] = useState(false);
  const location = useLocation();

  // const showHeader = !!location.pathname.endsWith("recording");
  const showHeader = recordingPathRegex.test(location.pathname);

  return (
    <Box>
      {user && authenticated ? <>
        <AppHeader user={user} setToggled={setToggled} toggled={toggled} reducedHeader={showHeader} />
          <Box sx={styles.container}>
            <Box sx={{ display: { md: 'none' } }}><SideNav toggled={toggled} setToggled={setToggled}/></Box>
            <Box component={'main'} sx={styles.mainSection}>
              <AppRoutes user={user} />
            </Box>
          </Box>
        </> : 
        <Box component={'main'} sx={styles.mainSection}>
            <AppRoutes user={null}/>
        </Box>
      }
      </Box>
    )
}

export default HomeContainer
```

that uses a custom hook for authentication for app routes. The useUser hook below, which checks if authenticated return an object with `{user, authenticated}` value:

```
export function useUser() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  const [authenticated, setAuthenticated] = useState(false);
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const location = useLocation();
  const subscribe = location.pathname.split("/")[1]
  useEffect(() => {
    async function getUserDetails() {
      const { authenticated, user } = await getAuthenticatedUser();
      if (!authenticated && location.pathname !== '/signup') {
        navigate('/signin');
        return;
      }
      else if (authenticated && (location.pathname === '/signup' || location.pathname === '/signin')) {
        navigate('/meetings');
        return;
      }
      setUser(user);
      setAuthenticated(authenticated);
    }
      getUserDetails();
  }, [navigate]);

  return { user, authenticated };
}
```

it uses a *getAuthenticatedUser* function and looks for an auth token saved in the browsers localStorage, if not found it requests for one  as below:

```
export async function getAuthenticatedUser() {
  const defaultReturnObject = { authenticated: false, user: null };
  try {
    const token = getTokenFromLocalStorage();
    if (!token) {
      return defaultReturnObject;
    }
    const response = await axios({
      method: 'GET',
      url: API_ROUTES.GET_USER,
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Token ${token}`
      }
    });
    const authenticated = response.data.status;
    return authenticated ? {authenticated: response.data.status, user: response.data.data} : false;
  }
  catch (err) {
    console.log('getAuthenticatedUser, Something Went Wrong', err);
    localStorage.clear();
    window.location.reload();
    return defaultReturnObject;
  }
}
```

the AppRoutes are defined for which ones are accessible for authenticated users i.e. they are logged in, and the others which are accessible i.e the landing page etc..

```
function AppRoutes(props) {

  const { user } = props;

  return (
    <>
      {user ? <Routes>
        <Route path='/dashboard' element={<Dashboard />} />
        ...
      </Routes>
        : <Routes>
          <Route path='' element={<LandingPage />} /> 
          <Route path='/signin' element={<Signin />} />
          <Route path='/signup' element={<Signup />} />
          <Route path='/reset-password' element={<ForgotPassword />} />
          <Route path='/faq' element={<FAQ />} />
        </Routes>
      }
    </>
  )
}

export default AppRoutes
```

Comment: Please confirm if you are wrapping your App in React.StrictMode. If yes, that is development env only. Remove that and check

Comment: StrictMode is usually the reason for double-rendering

Comment: As per React, if the app running in development mode and  strict mode, it will render twice. This is common behaviour in development mode. Once app is build into production this issue will not occur. 

if you still dont want double render remove <StrictMode> from root.
FYR: https://react.dev/reference/react/StrictMode